# GROUP BY id_recruiter ORDER BY ID DESC not working

Tags: mysql

MySQL Structure

| ID | id_recruiter | date_created | 
| 1  | 222    | 2018-08-15   | 
| 2  | 222    | 2018-08-16   | 
| 3  | 222    | 2018-08-17   |

MySQL Select

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id_recruiter=222 GROUP BY id_recruiter ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Result : | 1 | 222 | 2018-08-15 |

I want to get last record : | 3 | 222 | 2018-08-17 |

Please give me solution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query: with MAX aggregation

```
SELECT max(id) as id, id_recruiter,max(date_created) as date_created FROM table 
WHERE id_recruiter=222 
GROUP BY id_recruiter
```

Comment: Okay, I'm waiting for system allow to accpect. It takes me 5 minutes.